# how to keep 3d files online?

Tags: c#, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

I have been trying to build an app to take custom elements display on the  map, for this arcgis provides ***ModelSceneSymbol*** Class which takes two parameters: Uri and scale factor, when using in wpf (i am using System.Uri in this case) it is working great but as you know to make it work in an app  it has to be available in online, so i uploaded it to google drive to make it available online but it doesn't work, neither in wpf nor on the app side to combat this the arcgis solution is to zip the file and publish it which should be later unpacked and used from the app side,but to do this i need the data manager sample which is hard to work with, however i noticed something if there is a standalone link to the file it works great, else not so much,

stand alone link as in, the link that directs us to this.
[image: Stand alone link example]

not this
[image: Not Standalone link]

Most 3D object sites guide us to this part but not to the standalone links

btw the sample for model scene symbol and data manager.cs have been included here:
https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-dotnet/blob/main/src/WPF/ArcGISRuntime.WPF.Viewer/Samples/GraphicsOverlay/Animate3DGraphic/Animate3DGraphic.xaml.cs

https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-dotnet/blob/32a22e75c7f1d4b5f114856622c7364367cf870c/tools/metadata_tools/templates/solutions/XFI/Infrastructure/DataManager.cs#L214

is it possible to build a standalone link like this for 3d objects?

Comment: Deep links tend to rot over time. Would you please copy some examples into this question?

Comment: @SebastianWagner Can you try now?

Comment: Much better. Can you grab maybe a handful of C# lines over from the examples to clarify your question? But in general, I have the impression that you're going to need to properly host the data yourself in a website or similar.

Comment: The thing is to make the 3D Symbol appear in the mobile i have uploaded it to the Google Drive to  test it out but it never reflected in the map/scene, so i tried it in wpf where i used system uri which was working fine, so i tried again with google drive link but no result in wpf, the solution proposed by arcgis was to zip the file and upload it keept it online and later call nearly 6 programs to unzip the data and use it, somewhere in these 6 programs i am losing the file and the data isn't displaying again, that's why i am asking for stand alone link.

Comment: the links provided are opensource github links so i don't think they are going to be disappearnig any time soon so kindly try it over there